# Mac 10.6 Universal Binary scipy: cephes/specfun "_aswfa_" symbol not found

Tags: python, architecture, osx-snow-leopard, scipy, universal-binary

I can't get scipy to function in 32 bit mode when compiled as a i386/x86_64 universal binary, and executed on my 64 bit 10.6.2 MacPro1,1.

#### My python setup

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654837/run-an-os-x-universal-binary-in-32-bit-mode/1654855#1654855), I built a 32/64 bit intel universal binary of python 2.6.4 with the intention of using the `arch` command to select between the architectures. (I managed to make some universal binaries of a few libraries I wanted using lipo.) That all works. I then installed scipy according to the instructions on [hyperjeff's article](http://blog.hyperjeff.net/?p=160), only with more up-to-date numpy (1.4.0) and skipping the bit about moving numpy aside briefly during the installation of scipy.

Now, everything except scipy seems to be working as far as I can tell, and I can indeed select between 32 and 64 bit mode using `arch -i386 python` and `arch -x86_64 python`.

#### The error

Scipy complains in 32 bit mode:

```
$ arch -x86_64 python -c "import scipy.interpolate; print 'success'"
success
$ arch -i386 python -c "import scipy.interpolate; print 'success'"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from interpolate import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 13, in <module>
    import scipy.special as spec
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from basic import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/special/basic.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _cephes import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/special/_cephes.so, 2): Symbol not found: _aswfa_
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/special/_cephes.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/special/_cephes.so
```

#### Attempt at tracking down the problem

It looks like scipy.interpolate imports something called `_cephes`, which looks for a symbol called `_aswfa_` but can't find it in 32 bit mode. Browsing through scipy's source, I find an `ASWFA` subroutine in specfun.f. The only scipy product file with a similar name is specfun.so, but both that and _cephes.so appear to be universal binaries:

```
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/special/
$ file _cephes.so specfun.so 
_cephes.so: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
_cephes.so (for architecture i386): Mach-O bundle i386
_cephes.so (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
specfun.so: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
specfun.so (for architecture i386): Mach-O bundle i386
specfun.so (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

Ho hum. I'm stuck. Things I may try but haven't figured out how yet include compiling specfun.so myself manually, somehow.

I would imagine that scipy isn't broken for all 32 bit machines, so I guess something is wrong with the way I've installed it, but I can't figure out what.

I don't really expect a full answer given my fairly unique (?) setup, but if anyone has any clues that might point me in the right direction, they'd be greatly appreciated.

## **(edit)** More details to address questions:

I'm using gfortran (GNU Fortran from GCC 4.2.1 Apple Inc. build 5646).

Python 2.6.4 was installed more-or-less like so:

```
cd /tmp
curl -O http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.4/Python-2.6.4.tar.bz2
tar xf Python-2.6.4.tar.bz2
cd Python-2.6.4
# Now replace buggy pythonw.c file with one that supports the "arch" command:
curl http://bugs.python.org/file14949/pythonw.c | sed s/2.7/2.6/ > Mac/Tools/pythonw.c    
./configure --enable-framework=/Library/Frameworks --enable-universalsdk=/ --with-universal-archs=intel
make -j4
sudo make frameworkinstall
```

Scipy 0.7.1 was installed pretty much as described as [here](http://blog.hyperjeff.net/?p=160), but it boils down to a simple `sudo python setup.py install`.

It would indeed appear that the symbol is undefined in the i386 architecture if you look at the _cephes library with `nm`, as suggested by David Cournapeau:

```
$ nm -arch x86_64 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/special/_cephes.so | grep _aswfa_
00000000000d4950 T _aswfa_
000000000011e4b0 d _oblate_aswfa_data
000000000011e510 d _oblate_aswfa_nocv_data
(snip)
$ nm -arch i386 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/special/_cephes.so | grep _aswfa_
         U _aswfa_
0002e96c d _oblate_aswfa_data
0002e99c d _oblate_aswfa_nocv_data
(snip)
```

however, I can't yet explain its absence.

Comment: Probably scipy doesn't support building as universal binary yet - there is so much tricky stuff going on in the build process that it is not straight forward (numpy was only working recently). You could try filing a ticket on the scipy trac (and also try scipy svn - 0.7.1 is already a while ago so svn might contain a fix). Also where did you get your fortran compiler? Ones from here are recommended: http://r.research.att.com/tools/ - others generally dont have apple specific stuff like arch support

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using scipy compiled using macports?

```
sudo port install scipy +universal
```

(of course you must have the rest of the chain, `python`, `py26-numpy`compiled with the same option)

I get:

```
$ arch -x86_64 /opt/local/bin/python -c "import scipy.interpolate; print 'success'"
success

$ arch -i386 /opt/local/bin/python -c "import scipy.interpolate; print 'success'"
success
```

you may then use the setting and knowledge that the macports maintainers used to make your own compilation.

Comment: Does macports install python with a fixed version of pythonw.c? AFAIK there is a bug that makes `arch -i386` execute the 64 bit version also. If it works properly, sys.maxint should differ between the two, with 2147483647 for i386 and 9223372036854775807 for x86_64, but unpatched python will print the larger number for both flags. Could you check how your sys.maxint behaves with the various arch's?

Comment: You are right: `$ arch -i386 /opt/local/bin/python` gives me `>>> import sys; print sys.maxint` is `9223372036854775807` could not find anything about it on the macports' trac, however...

Answer (score 1):

How did you install scipy, for which python version, and with which fortran compiler ?

You may also want to check that the missing symbol is indeed in both archs (I don't remember off-hand where the function is, but you should be able to find ti by yourself pretty easily using a combination of nm/otool).

Comment: Updated the question with these details. I guess the thing to do is to attempt to compile _cephes manually.